# NewRelic::Agent::ForceRestartException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

What do these errors in newrelic_agent.log indicate and how can I address them?  I have recently made minor changes in newrelic.yml and restarted the server.  Reverting the changes doesn't help.

```
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Starting the New Relic agent in "production" environment.
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : To prevent agent startup add a NEWRELIC_ENABLE=false environment variable or modify the "production" section of your newrelic.yml
.
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Enabling the Request Sampler.
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Enabling the Request Sampler.
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Environment: production
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Dispatcher: passenger
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Application: production
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Connecting workers after forking.
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Installing DelayedJob instrumentation [part 1/2]
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Installing deferred Rack instrumentation
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Installing ActiveRecord instrumentation
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Installing Rails 3 Controller instrumentation
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Installing Rails 3.1/3.2 view instrumentation
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Installing Rails3 Error instrumentation
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
[11/26/13 10:08:17 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::Samplers::DelayedJobSampler not available: No DJ worker present
[11/26/13 10:08:18 -0800 prod-web02 (4558)] INFO : Doing deferred dependency-detection before Rack startup
[11/26/13 10:08:20 -0800 prod-web02 (4581)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/XXX/applications/XXX
[11/26/13 10:08:20 -0800 prod-web02 (4591)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/XXX/applications/XXX
[11/26/13 10:08:20 -0800 prod-web02 (4602)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/XXX/applications/XXX
[11/26/13 10:08:20 -0800 prod-web02 (4614)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/XXX/applications/XXX
**[11/26/13 10:08:26 -0800 prod-web02 (7931)] INFO : Failed to send timeslice data, trying again later. Error:
[11/26/13 10:08:26 -0800 prod-web02 (7931)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::ForceRestartException: ***Restart agent on stale config (account) method=metric_data launch=2013-11-20 02:07:17 config=2013-11-26 00:00:00
[11/26/13 10:08:57 -0800 prod-web02 (4661)] INFO : Reporting to: https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/XXX/applications/XXX
[11/26/13 10:09:26 -0800 prod-web02 (7931)] INFO : Failed to send timeslice data, trying again later. Error:
[11/26/13 10:09:26 -0800 prod-web02 (7931)] INFO : NewRelic::Agent::ForceRestartException: ***Restart agent on stale config (account) method=metric_data launch=2013-11-20 02:07:17 config=2013-11-26 00:00:00**
```

Answer (score 1):

Users will see this message (`NewRelic::Agent::ForceRestartException: **Restart agent on stale config (account)`) when their process is still using old configuration settings. If you restart the process, it should be able to find the updated config settings and this message should stop appearing. If you want New Relic to look more deeply into your logs and situation, it's best to file a support ticket at support.newrelic.com.

Comment: Thank you, @lauradiane.  Do I understand correctly that restarting the process means restarting  nginx+passenger (in my case) ?  This does not appear to help.  I guess it is time for a support ticket.

Comment: Restarting worked for me. I suspect (guess) the trigger for my seeing this problem was addition of "Key Transactions" in an app with config in a newrelic.yml rather than housed in the portal.